# organize output from query php

Tags: php

I am trying to output informations from query with mysqli_fetch_assoc but i can´t solve
my problem with the `while` loop . it will just print out title to every word instead once to every group of words.

```
$show="";
$showtitles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testcheck ORDER BY title")or die();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($showtitles )){
    $show_item= $row['item'];   
    $show_title= $row['title'];
    $show.='<div><b>'.$title.'</b> '.$show_item.'</div><br />';
}
```

Result :

```
<div>Fruits apple</div>

<div>Fruits bannan</div>

<div>words Common</div>

<div>words quality</div>

<div>words Enviroment</div>

<div>words Safety</div>
```

Currently this will output it like this. instead of title being displayed everytime i just want it once like.

```
<div>Fruits
<li>apple</li>
<li>bannan</<li></div>

<div>words
<li>Common</li>
<li>quality</li>
<li>Enviroment</li>
<li>Safety</li></div>
```

i have tried many diffrent versions of while loop but this example describes best the situation im in and what im trying to achive.

Comment: You're missing a `<ul>` around your `<li>`'s.

Comment: But to solve your problem, use a variable to save the title in, so on each iteration, you can check if the title is different from last ones. If so, output the title, otherwise don't.

Comment: `foreach` -> `add to array with` **`title`** `as key` -> `loop through array and print out desired html` -> **`profit`**

Comment: $new_array[ $row['title']]; would this be correct? and then do foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try grouping them in an array first. For example:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($showtitles )){
    $array[$row['item']][] = $row['title'];
}
```

And then loop this one out:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo "<strong>".$key."</strong";
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
       echo "<div>".$value2."</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can insert another $row[] into $key2?

Comment: What do you mean? Using `$array[$row['item']][]` creates a new layer in the array every time you call it. If you want an extra level, ofcourse you can. Its basically the same as in my answer.

Comment: well, its a multi array with 2 pair of keys from $array[$row['item']][] = $row['title']; could it be possible to add a value to $key2? inserting a third column info into the array?

Comment: You can do something like this: `$array[$row['item']][$item['id']]['title'] = $item['title']`, that allows you to pass extra information, for example: `$array[$row['item']][$item['id']]['date'] = $item['date']`

Comment: $array[$row['item']][$row['id']] = $row['title']; it worked fine and gave $key2 the id aswell, thanks for all help !